# form sending null value to the controller in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

here is my form and I'm sending it to the controller to get the data and insert it to the db with model but when I'm checking the post data in the controller it is null . here is my form :

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12" >
               <div class="widget-area no-padding blank">
               <div class="status-upload">
                 <?php
                 $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                   'action' => ['twit/send-twit'],
                 ]);
                 ?>
                  <?= $form->field($model,'twit')->textarea(); ?>
                   <?= Html::SubmitButton('ارسال',['class' => 'btn btn-success green']); ?>
                 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
               </div><!-- Status Upload  -->
             </div><!-- Widget Area -->
           </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and here is my controller which I'm checking the value of the posted field (twit) and it is always null :

```
    public function actionSendTwit()
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
var_dump($request->post('twit'));
die();
        if ($request->post('twit')){
            $twitContent = $request->post('twit');
            Twit::sendTwit($twitContent);
            \yii::$app->response->redirect('?r=twit/index',301)->send();
        }

    }
```

Comment: try `var_dump($request->post('Twit'));` `formName` must be same of Model Name

Comment: @DoubleH  it's working thank you very much . but I'm wondering , why should I use uppercase twit because i defined the name of the field with lowercase t ?

Comment: You are confusing. `post('Twit')` Here, Twit is model name not field name @SobhanBagheri

Comment: @NanaPartykar yeah but imagine i had another field in my db for example 'username' and i was getting the data from the form . in that case what would be instead of Twit ?

Comment: I'm explaining you in my answer. Wait for a minute @SobhanBagheri

Comment: @NanaPartykar allright thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Twit` is model name.

```
public function actionSendTwit()
{
  $modelTwit = new Twit();
  $request = Yii::$app->request;

  if ($modelTwit->load($request->post())) {

    $twitContent = $request->post('Twit');
        var_dump($twitContent);
    Twit::sendTwit($twitContent);
    \yii::$app->response->redirect('?r=twit/index',301)->send();
  }

}
```

**For User's Requirement.**

**View**

Now suppose, you are having two field. username and twit.(I assume these field are present in your DB Table.) So, When you use `$twitContent = $request->post('Twit');`. It uses **Twit Model** not the `field name.`

If you want to check values of username and twit. Use below method.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12" >
             <div class="widget-area no-padding blank">
               <div class="status-upload">
                 <?php
                 $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                   'action' => ['twit/send-twit'],
                 ]);
                 ?>
                  <?= $form->field($model,'twit')->textarea(); ?>
                  <?= $form->field($model,'username')->textinput(); ?>
                  <?= Html::SubmitButton('ارسال',['class' => 'btn btn-success green']); ?>
                 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
               </div><!-- Status Upload  -->
             </div><!-- Widget Area -->
           </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
<?
public function actionSendTwit()
{
  $modelTwit = new Twit();
  $request = Yii::$app->request;

  if ($modelTwit->load($request->post())) {

    $twitContent = $request->post('Twit'); //In this, model is called

    //If you want to see value then.
    print_r($twitContent['twit']);
    print_r($twitContent['username']);

    Twit::sendTwit($twitContent);
    \yii::$app->response->redirect('?r=twit/index',301)->send();
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: now i get it , all of the posted fields are in an array with the key of their names . thank you very much , very helpful

Comment: I updated it @SobhanBagheri. Just be cool and calm. Yii/Yii2 is easy. After getting these small basics. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

more clean way

```
public function actionSendTwit()
{
    if ($this->request->isPost) {
        $form_data = Yii::$app->request->post('Twit');//same as model name
        $twitId = $form_data['id'];
        $twitCtn = $form_data['content'];
    }
}
```