# How to get value of attribute in controller from Form in view Yii 2

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I created a table named (users) it has two columns: `name` and `pass`. 
In view I created form like this:

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>

<div class="form-group">
  <?= $form->field($model, 'user') ?>
  <?= $form->field($model, 'password') ?>
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

So I need to pass this two attributes to controller to insert into data base.

Comment: you could take a look at this guide https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-forms

Comment: Thank you but it is not helpful Because i need to insert this value into database and i don't know how to pass value from view and how to deal with it into controller and the how to insert into data base in controller

Comment: Have you really read  the content of the link??   .. then if you have done this tell me what you have not understand .. because the link  describes all the flow and all the parts necessary to do exactly what you ask ..

Comment: anyway i have posted  an aswer  hope is clear

Comment: Thank you again I read it my problem now something like this the when i get the name and pass from view in controller the controller get null value from view something like this: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, NULL)

Comment: Your column name is 'user' as in your code  or 'name' as in your error message .??? .  seems you are using a wrong column name  (model field name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YourController.php
assuing you have an Create action for manage your insert  in db 
and a create view for manage the user input (a view  for only display the correct result )

```
    <?php

    namespace app\controllers;

    use Yii;
    use yii\web\Controller;
    use app\models\EntryForm;

    class YourController extends Controller
    {
        // ...existing code...

        public function actionCreate()
        {
            $model = new User();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
                // valid data received in $model

                // 
                if( $model->save()){
                    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
                } else {
                    // this is just for debug  
                    var_dump('not inserted');
                    die();
                }

            } else {
                // either the page is initially displayed or there is some validation error
                return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
            }


        // render the initial page per allow to the user input 
        return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
       }  

       ....
   }
```

Comment: Many thanks this link solved my second problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434692/form-sending-null-value-to-the-controller-in-yii2

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can get your post form in this way:

```
Yii::$app->request->post()
```

And this way you can load the value into your model

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
```

Here you can find a [starting point](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-forms)